# Flickering on page load when using position: absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, css-position

Basically the title explains it all.
When the page loads, it first loads the little div for the left hand side with the + in it. After that it loads the page and positions it.

How can i prevent this? It is in every page, so it is quite anoying.
http://www.netwerkhoreca.nl

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply a "flash of unstyled content" (FOUC) - basically the styling you want is only being applied when the Javascript kicks in after DOM load, so until all the elements are on the page you only have the styling from the CSS file for that element. The best approach is to  make sure it has an appropriate style with just CSS (possibly `display: none` for this as it seems like a JS widget), then use JS to add the other styling you need for widget behaviour (like `position: fixed`, etc).

See [this excellent article](http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/) for some solutions.

Comment: I think you are right that the basic style loads first and after that the js loads. I looked at your link, but it did not help me (or i did not understand it right). I tried the codes, but still cannot manage to get it working.

Comment: Well, firstly do you want that element to be at all visible if the user doesn't have Javascript enabled? If not, that solves your problem straight away - set it to `display: none` in the CSS, then back to `display: auto` (or `block`/`inline`/whatever) in JS. That way it remains hidden until the script has fully loaded.

Comment: the CSS part i understand. though i am not really good with JS. i have set display: none in css, now in the js script... should i add style.display = 'block' just after the fixedPosition: true, part? I guess not, since it is not working out for me :)

Comment: Could you post your JS code that creates that widget? Essentially yes, just find the part of the code that manipulates that element and add the style declaration `myElement.css('display','block');`, or add it to the config object if it accepts one.

Comment: i did what you said, still no result. the js code is hardcoded in the head starting at line 90 from www.netwerkhoreca.nl. BTW i appreciate the help sofar. hopefully at the time we are done i can mark this as the right answer :)

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you did! Yeah, that won't work like that. Try adding this at **line 91** in your markup: `$('slide-out-div').css('display','block');`

Comment: as you can see i added your line, but still no luck :( it still does not display. BTW: sorry for the delay, had a quick lunch

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - it should read `$('.slide-out-div').css('display','block');` (I missed the dot before the class name)

Comment: you sir.... are awesome! thank you for the time you spend on this. have been a great help!